# canonical file path in java - optimization problem?

Tags: java, optimization

My file structure has a symbolic link to a directory /home/me/myDir -> /some/other/dir. 
This link gets updated by another process and the notifies my process. Upon notification I attempt to get the new canonical path:

```
public static String getPath()
{
   File file = new File("/home/me/myDir");
   if(file.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         String canonical = file.getCanonicalPath();
         return canonical;
      }
      catch ...
   }
```

}

The problem is that after the link is changed (an i have verified it changes) it is taking 3-5 times of calling the above getPath() method for to actually get the new path before that the previous path is returned. The only thing I can think of is that java might be optimizing this method and returning the old path. Any ideas or insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try disabling Java's canonicalization cache.  This can be done by setting the system properties `sun.io.useCanonCaches` and `sun.io.useCanonPrefixCache` to false.

By default, canonical file names are cached for 30 seconds (read from source [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ExpiringCache.java.html)).